# Uploading build from buddybuild to iTunes Connect failed

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, app-store-connect, buddy-build

I am using BuddyBuild to manage all my builds and to upload them to iTunesConnect. For the last month and even yesterday everything was working perfectly and smoothly. For some reason, today I can't upload the build. All the tests are successful but when it's time to upload it, it fails with no explanation. 
All I changed (a part from a couple of lines of code) is I added the new iOS Marketing Icon.
Did anyone had this issue? Is there a way to know how to fix it or why is it happening? Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the iTunes Connect API isn't great at providing feedback. Have you been able to finally upload?

If not, our recommendation is to download your IPA from the Build details, and try to upload it manually using the "Application Loader" app. This app usually returns better feedback than the API.

Let me know if this help!